# Javascript - Onload function which submits a html form when user klicks alert button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, submit

I have a HTML form which should be executed when the user klicks YES in an alert box.

What I need:

- Alert Box window.onload with Yes and No option
- If Yes is clicked the submit form must be executed
- If No is clicked the user will be redirected to previous page

So basically I need an onclick event when the user clicks Yes in the alert box.

Can't find anything helpful.

This is my form.

```
        <form id="loginForm" name="login" method="post" action="">
            <input id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo "$name";?>" class="rounded" title="No special characters" hidden/>
            <input id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo "info@info.com";?>" class="rounded"  title="No special characters" hidden/> 
            <input type="submit" class="blueButton" value="START CHAT" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first - you need to write the value of **value** attribute in **input** tag with correct quotes. You should either use template literals, or use escape character or simply enclose the outer string with double quotes and the inner one with single quotes (or vice-versa).

Then, you need a **prompt** which is defined under the **window.onload()** method. If the user clicks *OK*, you find the form with the given name on the window and submit it. If the user clicks on *Cancel*, you simply redirect the user to some other page.

Notice that you need to define a value for the **action** attribute in your form tag.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to start chat?")) {
    // submit form (define an action in the form tag; currently redirecting to some page, let's say action_page.php)
    document.forms["login"].submit();
  } else {
    //redirect to some other page
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="loginForm" name="login" method="post" action="/action_page.php">
    <input id="name" name="name" value='<?php echo "$name";?>' class="rounded"
    title="No special characters" hidden/> <input id="email" name="email"
    value='<?php echo "info@info.com";?>' class="rounded" title="No special
    characters" hidden/>
    <input type="submit" class="blueButton" value="START CHAT" />
</form>
```